# Node.js - Basic example not working

Tags: node.js

I have been trying to figure out why i cant get even the most basic Node.js application to run, all day. I have installed Node on my Media Temple (dv) server in the root using PuTTy NOT on my local machine.

When i do 'node --version' it shows me the version, which tells me that Node is correctly installed. However when i attempt to do the basic 'HTTP' example it doesnt work when i go to http://mysite.com:1337, instead the connection just times out.

The JS is below:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "mysite.com");

console.log('Server running at http://mysite.com:1337/');
```

Node.js really interests me so would be good if i can understand why it isnt working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In chat, we found out that this example works, which means that it's not a node issue: https://gist.github.com/1339846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337);

console.log('Server running at http://mysite.com:1337/');
```

Without specifying the host?

Comment: Is mysite.com hosted on a VPS somewhere and you are trying to access it from your home computer? If so, check if the port 1337 is open for the public (this can be the case for Amazon EC2 for example).

Comment: I added the port 1337 to the outgoing and ingoing ALLOW list on my Plesk panel. Then went and retried all your suggested answers but still nothing!

Comment: Log into your VPS remotely (ssh) and do: curl http://127.0.0.1:1337/ and tell me if it's showing anything. If it showing "Hello world", then it's definitely a port blocking problem.

Comment: Right so i connected as root to my web server using PuTTy and put in the code you said. And it returned:

    `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`

Comment: Are you sure you installed Node correctly? Make a file called simpletest.js and put: console.log('test') into it. Then node simpletest.js and tell me if it returns something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4725/discussion-between-alessioalex-and-itsphil)

Answer (score 2):

Change `listen(1337, "mysite.com")` to `listen(1337, "0.0.0.0")`, that should work.

Comment: No Cigar im afraid. Thought id also try 'localhost', '192.168.0.1', '127.0.0.1' but still nothing. @Raynos your suggestion didnt work either :(

Comment: @itsphil go to localhost:1337 or if it's a remote server make sure you open/forward port 1337

Comment: @Raynos im not sure that MT will let me open any ports up. Whats strange is 2 months ago i experimented with Node and on the same server and it worked fine. This time around i removed Node and reinstalled it and have had troubles ever since.

Comment: @itsphil have you tried listening on port 80? and then going to mysite.com ?

Comment: I just did that yeah and it through up an error:

`node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:614:11)
    at Array.0 (net.js:704:26)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)`

Comment: @itsphil turn off whatever else is in port 80

Comment: @Raynos as per my comments above to alessio "I added the port 1337 to the outgoing and ingoing ALLOW list on my Plesk panel. Then went and retried all your suggested answers but still nothing!"